# Rspec unit test for updating a property of a model

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, rspec, to-do-list

I know how to write simple RSpec tests and unit tests. I just want to know if this is good enough or if there are any improvements I can make.

I intend to test the the `toggle_property` method of the `TaskItemUserReference` model which updates the property, `completed` from `false` to `true` or vice versa.

*Relationships*

User has many Tasks through TaskUserReference
Task has many Users through TaskUserReference

TaskItem has many Users through TaskItemUserReference
User has many TaskItem through TaskItemUserReference

```
#Factories

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task do
    name Faker::Lorem.sentence(2)
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task_user_reference do
    user
    task
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task_item do
    name Faker::Lorem.sentence(3)
    task
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :task_item_user_reference do
    task_item
    user
    active true
    completed false
  end
end

# RSPEC test
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Task, type: :model do

  let(:owner) { create(:user) }
  let(:task) { create(:task, owner: owner) }
  let(:user) { create(:user) }
  let(:task_item) { create(:task_item, task: task) }

  before do
    user.tasks << task
    user.task_item_user_references.create(
      user_id: user.id,
      completed: true,
      task_item: task_item
    )
  end

  describe "task_items" do
    it "updates status" do
      task_item_user_reference = user.task_item_user_references.first
      task_item_user_reference.toggle_property(:completed)

      expect(task_item_user_reference.completed).to eq(false)
     end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't need the whole user-task-task item setup for the test you provided. It's actually a TaskItemUserReference spec, not Task spec.

```
RSpec.describe TaskItemUserReference, type: :model do

  describe "#toggle_property" do
    it "updates property" do
      task_item_user_reference = TaskItemUserReference.new(completed: true)

      expect do 
        task_item_user_reference.toggle_property(:completed)
      end.to change {task_item_user_reference.completed}.from(true).to(false)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `TaskItemUserReference` seems to make sense.